# Laravel 5.4 inconsistent duplicate inserts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, vagrant

I get inconsistent duplicate inserts when running the following Laravel code: (I know I'm breaking all best practices, but this example code isolates the problem.)

App/routes/web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; // NOTE: I am using the query builder, not a model
use Carbon\Carbon;

Route::get('formtest', function() {
  return view('testing.index');
});
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('formtest', function(Request $request) {
  DB::table('pers2_testing_inserts')
    ->insert([
      'data' => $request["test"],
      'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
      'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
});
```

App/resources/views/testing/index.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TESTING</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off" onsubmit="disableAndSubmit(event)">
  <input type="text" name="test" id="text_box">
  <input type="submit" id="submit_button">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var text_box = document.getElementById('text_box');
  var submit_button = document.getElementById('submit_button');
  var form = document.getElementById('form');

  function disableAndSubmit(e) {
    submit_button.disabled = true;
    if(text_box.value !== '') {
      form.submit();
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      submit_button.disabled = null;
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My project is built in Laravel 5.4, PHP 7.1.7. I develop on a Mac, using vagrant as a virtual machine. My production server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Computer with XAMPP v3.2.2. The inconsistent duplicate inserting ONLY happens on the production server. Here is a screenshot of a few tests on the server.

[image: PHPMyAdmin Showing Tests]

I have inserts all over in my program, and any one of them can duplicate, and it's inconsistent. It shouldn't be that way. Is there something I should change in my XAMPP configuration? PHP configuration? Is there a workaround that I can implement that would prevent this from happening on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var text_box = document.getElementById('text_box');
  var submit_button = document.getElementById('submit_button');
  var form = document.getElementById('form');

  function disableAndSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submit_button.disabled = true;
    if(text_box.value !== '') {
      form.submit();

      return true;
    } else {

      submit_button.disabled = false;

      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Return statements eh? I didn't think the problem was in the javascript, but after a bunch of tests, it seemed to work. Thank you!

Comment: @n8jadams the problem not just at return. the preventDefault() is really crucial. if you want to submit using javascript you need prevent it from the start. so html won't submit it at first time it render the script.

Comment: I noticed that change as well. Thanks again. :)